# How do you force a paragraph in html to not wrap?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have been trying to force a `<p>` element to not wrap by itself so the formatting works better (the p element is meant to be a "hashtag") As you can see if you run the code you get the answered text way below the Dummy Text - it's meant to be inline.
This is my code:

```css
.answered {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 90px;
 background-color: green;
        text-align: center; 
}
h3 {
display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<h3>Dummy Text...</h3><p class="answered">Answered</p>
```

**Update**
The answered text is now centre aligned and the h2 tag is inline-block
The question has been answered in the comments...

Comment: the h3 need to also be inline block ..

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's already an inline-block

Comment: How do you think the h3 is inline-block? Nothing in your code would indicate that, and by default, all headings are block level.

Comment: @j08691 Oops - realised mistake - I meant that the p is inline-block - I have edited that h3 now.

Comment: So then what's your question? Both elements are on the same line now.

Comment: @j08691 see the new update...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stylesheet:

```
h3, .answered{
   display: inline-block; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Jim, See the image, isn't this you want? Try to add `!important` if doesn't work. You might have other css in the higher level.

Comment: @Jim Why did you accept this answer? According to your own code, you're already using inline-block on both of your elements.

Comment: @j08691 Because I edited the code to include inline-block - and  Temani Afif has not posted an answer

Comment: @Jim Huh? So you edited the code in your question to include code that you weren't actually using?

Answer (score 0):

Try `<span>`instead of the p element. The p element is for defining paragraphs, which start on a new line. If you aren’t writing a new paragraph, `<span>` is a better choice as it does not use a new line.

Comment: Try what instead of the what element - You may have missed something...

Comment: Missed putting my code in code blocks! Fixed. Thanks for the catch.